# Check if user has opened every viewcontroller

Tags: ios, swift

I would like to know, is it possible to check if user has opened every `viewcontroller` that application has?

I would like to do it because I give user badges and it is the one I would like to give.

I assume I have to store something into `userDefaults` and somehow gather the info and then do what I want to do, am I right? If I am right then should I do some global variable and add count every time user opens new `viewcontroller`?

Any info is appreciated.

Comment: Do you want to manage it even if user closed the app ?

Comment: Nono, just if user has opened the app. But I can't be sure if he closes the app before he is been on every viewcontroller.

Comment: So if the use closes the app, you don't want to save how far he has reached.

Comment: I want. Sorry if I misunderstood Rajat question.

Comment: How many view controllers do you expect the app to have?

Comment: Do you have a plan to use CoreData?

Comment: No, I didn't plan to use coreData

Comment: What is the count of your View Controller ?

Comment: I have about 8 viewcontrollers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make an option set to represent every viewController.  In each viewControllers ViewDidAppear, read and update a field from Userdefaults that stores the option set of displayed viewControllers then write it back to Userdefaults.

```
    struct UserDefaultsKey {
        static let displayedViewControllers = "displayedViewControllers"
    }

    struct DisplayedViewControllers: OptionSet {
        let rawValue: Int

        static let vc1 = DisplayedViewControllers(rawValue: 1 << 0)
        static let vc2 = DisplayedViewControllers(rawValue: 1 << 1)
        static let vc3 = DisplayedViewControllers(rawValue: 1 << 2)
        static let vc4 = DisplayedViewControllers(rawValue: 1 << 3)
        static let all = [vc1, vc2, vc3, vc4]
    }

    class vc1: UIViewController {
        override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
            super.viewDidAppear(true)
            var displayedViewControllers = DisplayedViewControllers(rawValue: UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: UserDefaultsKey.displayedViewControllers))
            displayedViewControllers.insert(.vc1)
            UserDefaults.standard.set(displayedViewControllers.rawValue, forKey: UserDefaultsKey.displayedViewControllers)
        }
    }

    func haveAllViewControllersBeenDisplayed() -> Bool {
        let displayedViewControllers = DisplayedViewControllers(rawValue: UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: UserDefaultsKey.displayedViewControllers))
        for controller in DisplayedViewControllers.all {
            if displayedViewControllers.contains(controller) == false {
                return false
            }
        }
        return true
    }
```

Comment: I think it is the best solution. But I have one question. To add badge, I should do it before returning true? Or where should I check if it contains all keys?

Comment: It depends where/when you want to do your badge checking logic.  If you want to reward the badge as soon as they view the last ViewController then at the end of each viewDidAppear put something like if haveAllViewControllersBeenDisplayed()  { awardBadge() }

Comment: In method `haveAllViewControllersAreDisplayed` you can also do this check  `displayedViewControllers == .all`

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in this way, if you are using UINavigationController then at the end of every UINavigationController Stack set a true key in UserDefaul like this

```
UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "NavigationStack1")
```

Now let us suppose your App has 4 diffrent type of Navigations then you can set those like this, with diffrent key

```
UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "NavigationStack1")
UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "NavigationStack2")
UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "NavigationStack3")
UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "NavigationStack4")
```

Then at the end of every UINavigationController's Stack you need to check whether user has visited all the Navigations like this

```
if  UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "NavigationStack1")&&UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "NavigationStack2")&&UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "NavigationStack3")&&UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "NavigationStack4"){
    // Give Badge to user
}
```

Also you can do it for each UIViewController, in the viewDidLoad of each controller set the key for that viewController to true then, check the result of all the key, in this way you will be able to know whether user has visited all the UIViewController of your app.

Answer (score 1):

Assume you have three ViewControllers: ViewController1, ViewController2, ViewController3

**Method 1: Array of ViewController names in the NSUserDefaults:**

Maintain a Set of opened ViewController Names: (The Set can be serialized/deserialized to NSUserDefaults)

```
var openedViewControllers = Set<String>()
```

Once viewController1 has been opened, you insert it to the set.

```
openedViewControllers.insert(viewController1Name)
```

How to check if all viewController were opened:

```
if openedViewController.count == 3{
   //All three viewControllers were opened
}
```

**Method 2: Use Bit Masking:** (will be save as normal UInt64)

You use an UInt64 = 0 and every view controller will be mapped to a bit of Int64.
Once you open that view controller you changed the corresponding bit from 0 to 1.

Example: 
 ViewController1 (opened), ViewController2(never opened), ViewController3(opened) => BitMask will be 1010000....

How to check if all viewController were opened:

```
if BitMask == 3{
   //All three viewControllers were opened
}
```

N.B. With the second approach, you can only have 64 ViewControllers in you app

Answer (score 0):

You could save an array of Bool in CoreData with the list of the View Controller name. And check it every time a ViewController is open.

You can also use UserDefaults.standard.setValue and stock your Dictionary or Array.

Hope it helps!